# Open Graph Meta Tags are marked as Invalid

Tags: facebook-opengraph

My site is a WordPress site, version 5.02
[http://www.baddog3d.com][1]

I cannot determine why the debugger keeps tagging the meta tag: *og;url* as invalid. I have tried with "http://" and "https://" and headless but still receive the same error.

These are my meta tags that the Yoast plugin creates for the head section

```
<meta property="og:locale" content="en_US" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:title" content="3D Modeling Services" />
<meta property="og:description" content="BadDog offers custom 3D modeling and visualization services, Logo Animations, Product Prototyping, Architectural exterior or interior renders" />
<meta property="og:url" content="https://www.baddog3d.com/" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="BadDog 3D Modeling" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="xxxxxxxxxxx7117" />
<meta property="og:image" content="https://www.baddog3d.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/baddog3dHPfinal.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="https://www.baddog3d.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/baddog3dHPfinal.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content="1200" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="630" />
```

**Facebook Debugger:** https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/

**The Error:** *Object at URL 'https://www.baddog3d.com/' of type 'website' is invalid because the given value '/' for property 'og:url' could not be parsed as type 'url'.

Comment: remove the last '/' from the url

Comment: Hey Xion...This is the Open Graph tag from another site that is an almost identical site and I get no errors, like the previously mentioned issue.  There is "/" at the end of the "og:url" tag in this one too.      

    <meta property="og:url" content="https://drone-scapes.com/" />